# ajax GET call returns error after successful executing method on web api

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

Background : loading html page in iFrame control of aspx page

Problem : I am having a Ajax call in html client body's onload to web api service.GET Method on server is executed successfully,but when control returns to client error section of the ajax call is executed with parameters having error as response text.

**Ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:2940/api/wrds2/',
    type: "GET",
    data: { pOrdKey: OrderKey.toString(), pRptKey: ReportKey.toString(), pGroupKey: GroupKey.toString() },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        Err_jSonStr = data;  <--- Some Variable
        _FormData_Assigner(Err_jSonStr); -- Some function

    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
        debugger;
        alert(x.responseText);
    }
});
```

**CodeBehind** - Web Method:

```
public InterviewDFS Get(string pOrdKey, string pRptKey, string pGroupKey)
{
    try
    {
        InterviewDFS lObj_InterviewDFS = null;
        if (cObjADO_DAL == null)
            cObjADO_DAL = new AdoDotNetDataAccessLayer();
        lObj_InterviewDFS = cObjADO_DAL.GetInterviewDFS(pOrdKey, pRptKey, pGroupKey);
        return lObj_InterviewDFS;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Web api return lObj_InterviewDFS with proper values.
Please find me the possible error.

---

Update : After some trials , i found that i is causing problem when client page is in different project and web api is different project ..............! i know you need to implement cors but i am totally unaware of it. please provide me the solution

Comment: please also put your output from ajax here

Comment: post error msg pls , and remove debugger alert response

Comment: 1. x and y variables return Error as text                                       2. ResponceText proprty of x return TEXT undefined                          3. message in console after ajax call returns to client                  --------------------------------------------------------------------XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:2940/api/wrds2/?pOrdKey=1209022828&pRptKey=DFS&pGroupKey=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:52466' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: try see [Access_control_CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use different port from your client into API, it will blocked by HTTP access control (CORS)
so, first you need to enable the API to accept your CORS request, you can do that with the web.config like this:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Accept-Encoding" value="gzip, deflate, sdch" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, RequestVerificationToken, Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Method" value="PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="false" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

And then you need to put this header on every request that you made on the ajax jquery :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
```

Comment: How can i mention header on request made in Html.                    **Note**: do you need to install cors related packages on your machine.